# Display civilid front and back images onclick event using popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I put the code below. if you get any idea let me know that. I want both civilid images front 
and back images display when i click the event.Anyone can solve my problem?

---

### crm/DisplayCategoryPicture.aspx

**VB**

```
 Private Sub CusImgShow()
    Try
        Const SQL As String = "SELECT Civilimg1,civilimg2 FROM [NewCus] WHERE [Cust_ID] = @Cust_ID2"
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(SQL, myConnection)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cust_ID", Request.QueryString("Cust_ID"))
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
        If myReader.Read Then
            Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG"
            Response.BinaryWrite(myReader("Civilimg1"))
            Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG"
            Response.BinaryWrite(myReader("Civilimg2"))
        End If
        myReader.Close()          
        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)'
    End Try
End Sub
```

---

**aspx:**

```
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height ="40" Width ="60" 
     ImageUrl='<%# Eval(("Cust_ID"),"~/crm/DisplayCategoryPicture.aspx?Cust_ID={0}")%>' 
     onclick="CreatepopUp1(this.src);" />
```

**javascript:**

```
 var Popup; 
 function CreatepopUp1(url) {
     Popup = window.open(url, "Popup", 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=120,height=250,left = 190,top = 262');
     Popup.focus();
 }
```

Comment: Where is the C#? What is the problem?

Comment: you are asking if anyone can solve your problem, but you forgot to mention what **IS** the problem?

Comment: problem is getting only one image through using binary write .I want get two images at onclick the event.